# Parse Python List

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, tuples

I have a JSON data type raw.json

```
{"time": 12.640, "name": "machine1", "value": 24.0}
{"time": 12.645, "name": "machine2", "value": 0.0}
{"time": 12.65002, "name": "machine3", "value": true}
{"time": 12.66505, "name": "machine4", "value": 1.345}
{"time": 12.67007, "name": "machine5", "value": 5.068}
{"time": 12.67508, "name": "machine4", "value": 1.075}
{"time": 12.6801, "name": "machine5", "value": 2.0868}
{"time": 12.6851, "name": "machine4", "value": 0.0}
{"time": 12.6901, "name": "machine5", "value": 12.633}
{"time": 12.69512, "name": "machine5", "value": 13.13}
{"time": 12.70013, "name": "machine3", "value": false}
{"time": 12.70515, "name": "machine3", "value": false}
{"time": 12.71016, "name": "machine3", "value": false}
{"time": 12.71517, "name": "machine5", "value": 131.633}
```

So in my python script i am able to generate a line by line read and generate a list

```
import json

data = [];
timestamp =[];
with open('raw.json') as f:
    for line in f:
       data.append(json.loads(line))
    f.close()

for idx, val in enumerate(data):
   time = data[idx]['time']
   name = data[idx]['name']
   value = data[idx]['value']
   data_list = idx+1, time, name, value
   print data_list
```

output:

```
(1, 12.64, u'machine1', 24.0)
(2, 12.645, u'machine2', 0.0)
(3, 12.65002, u'machine3', True)
(4, 12.66505, u'machine4', 1.345)
(5, 12.67007, u'machine5', 5.068)
(6, 12.67508, u'machine4', 1.075)
(7, 12.6801, u'machine5', 2.0868)
(8, 12.6851, u'machine4', 0.0)
(9, 12.6901, u'machine5', 12.633)
(10, 12.69512, u'machine5', 13.13)
(11, 12.70013, u'machine3', False)
(12, 12.70515, u'machine3', False)
(13, 12.71016, u'machine3', False)
(14, 12.71517, u'machine5', 131.633)
```

I want to sort this data such that i can have individual lists (arrays) that i can use. e.g.

```
machine1 = [12.640, 24.0];
machine2 = [12.645, 0.0];
machine3 = [
12.65002,true
12.70013,false
12.70515,false
12.71016,false
]; 
machine4 = [
12.66505 1.345
12.67508 1.075
12.6851 0.0
];
```

and so on also in addition how can i search this tuple or the list directly to generate meta data like sum/average for machine1, machine 2 etc.

```
Sum_Machine1 = 24;
Sum_Machine2 = 0;....
```

Comment: i tried to search `[x[2] for x in data_list].index('machine1')`

also 

`[item for item in data_list if 0 in item]` //to search for the location where the values are zero, did not even get to try searching for the string

Comment: also tried `[i for i, v in enumerate(data_list) if v[2] == 'machine1']`

Comment: Check out pandas if you mean to do a lot of this stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First Solution

Here is how I approach the problem:

```
import json
import collections

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # Load file into data
    with open('raw.json') as f:
        data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]

    # Calculate count and total
    time_total = collections.defaultdict(float)
    time_count = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for row in data:
        time_count[row['name']] += 1
        time_total[row['name']] += row['time']

    # Calculate average
    time_average = {}
    for name in time_count:
        time_average[name] = time_total[name] / time_count[name]

    # Report
    for name in sorted(time_count):
        print '{:<10} {:2} {:8.2f} {:8.2f}'.format(
            name,
            time_count[name],
            time_total[name],
            time_average[name])
```

### Discussion

- `data` is a list of `dict` with keys such as *name*, *time*, ...
- I used three additional dictionaries to keep track of the count, total, and average per machine.
- I assume you want your calculation based on the time value. If not, it is an easy fix.
- The `defaultdict` is a nice way to tally numbers. If an int value is not already created, it will be created and assign value of 0, very convenient. You should look it up.

---

## Second Solution

Here is a different approach: since your data looks like a table, why not use a database to handle your data. The advantage of this approach is you don't have to do calculations yourself.

```
import json
import sqlite3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create an in-memory database for calculation
    connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_table')
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE time_table (name text, time real)')
    connection.commit()

    # Load file into database
    with open('raw.json') as f:
        for line in f:
            row = json.loads(line)
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO time_table VALUES (?,?)', (row['name'], row['time']))
            connection.commit()

    # Report: print the name, count, sum, and average
    cursor.execute('SELECT name, COUNT(time), SUM(time), AVG(time) FROM time_table GROUP BY name')
    print '%-10s %8s %8s %8s' % ('NAME', 'COUNT', 'SUM', 'AVERAGE')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print '%-10s %8d %8.2f %8.2f' % row

    connection.close()
```

### Output

```
NAME          COUNT      SUM  AVERAGE
machine1          1    12.64    12.64
machine2          1    12.64    12.64
machine3          4    50.77    12.69
machine4          3    38.03    12.68
machine5          5    63.45    12.69
```

### Discussion

- In this solution, I created an in-memory **SQLite3** database
- Since we are only interested in the *name* and *time* columns, the table only contains those two.
- We got all the statistical functions such as `SUM`, `COUNT`, and `AVG` for free, just by using the database.

---

## Addition to First Solution

To answer the question: Given *machine5*, how can I get the last value? By that, I assume you want to filter your data down to those containing *machine5*, then sort them by time and select the last row. For the first solution, append the following block of code and run it:

```
# Filter data: prints all rows with 'machine5'
print '\nFilter by machine5'
machine5 = [row for row in data if row['name'] == 'machine5']
machine5 = sorted(machine5, key=lambda row: int(row['time']))
pprint(machine5)

# Get the last instance
print '\nLast instance of machine5:'
latest_row = machine5[-1]
pprint(latest_row)
```

Don't forget to add the following at the beginning of the script:

```
from pprint import pprint
```

### Output

```
Filter by machine5
[{u'name': u'machine5', u'time': 12.67007, u'value': 5.068},
 {u'name': u'machine5', u'time': 12.6801, u'value': 2.0868},
 {u'name': u'machine5', u'time': 12.6901, u'value': 12.633},
 {u'name': u'machine5', u'time': 12.69512, u'value': 13.13},
 {u'name': u'machine5', u'time': 12.71517, u'value': 131.633}]

Last instance of machine5:
{u'name': u'machine5', u'time': 12.71517, u'value': 131.633}
```

### Discussion

If you do not want to sort the rows by time, then remove the `sorted()` line and that will give you the unsorted output.

Comment: if i still wanted to get individual arrays or tables for each machines i.e. `machine1 = [12.640, 24.0];
machine2 = [12.645, 0.0];
machine3 = [
12.65002,true
12.70013,false
12.70515,false
12.71016,false
]; 
machine4 = [
12.66505, 1.345
12.67508, 1.075
12.6851, 0.0
];`
How would you go about it, is there a benefit to create an SQL DB vs using a collection in each case

Comment: I highly recommend against having separate variables to store data like that. It makes computation much harder than it should.

Comment: What would be your suggestion to search the dictionary for lets say the last known value and timestamp of machine-5 i.e. timestamp = 12.7517, and value = 131.633. Given the fact that dictionaries are not ordered based on the value entry, but my goal is to retrieve the last "value" of a particular key ("machine1")

Comment: Please see the **Addition to First Question** section I just added.

Comment: once i was able to construct a dictionary `machine5 = [row for row in data if row['name'] == 'machine5']` i get all the machine name values, but if i want to total the value names, i.e. 5.068+2.0868+12.633+13.13+131.633.

Answer (score 1):

Make each row a class (not strictly necessary but nice), overload **cmp** and use sort

```
class MachineInfo:

    def __init__(self, info_time, name, value):
        self.info_time = info_time
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

def cmp_machines(a, b):
    return cmp(a.name, b.name)
```

Also sort takes an optional comparison function..

```
info = [... fill this with MachineInfo instances here ...]

# then call 
info = sorted(info, cmp_machines)

# or to sort in place
info.sort(cmp_machines)

# alternatively add a  __cmp__ method to MachineInfo and that will get used by default
```

There's fancier ways of doing it.. https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting
But it's nice to keep things simple and obvious.